# How to view linked data in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have two tables, described as below.

**Table 1: countries**

```
c_id, int
c_name, varchar(20) (PK)
```

Sample records in this table are.

```
c_id | c_name
1 | USA
2 | UK
3 | PAK
```

**Table 2: immigrants**

```
i_id, int
i_name, varchar(20)
i_country, int (FK)
```

Sample records in this table are.

```
i_id | i_name | i_country
1 | John | 1
2 | Graham | 2
3 | Ali | 3
```

**Question 1:**

I want to create two classes (tables) in OrientDB but I need to know what should be the data type of the FK field and what to insert in it. I mean what should I write in query to insert the id of the PK table. Does it need to be @rid? How?

**QUESTION 2:**

What is the OrientDB SQL for producing the following output.

```
i_id | i_name | i_country | c_id | c_name
1 | John | 1 | 1 | USA
2 | Graham | 2 | UK
3 | Ali 3 | PAK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with OrientDB you can avoid the creation of FK fields and join operations by using direct Edge links between records. For example:

```
create class Country extends V;
create class Immigrant extends V;
create class comesFrom extends E;

create property Country.c_id integer;
create property Country.c_name String;
create property Immigrant.i_id integer;
create property Immigrant.i_name String;

insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (1, USA);
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (2, UK);
insert into Country(c_id, c_name) values (3, PAK);

insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name) values (1, John);
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name) values (2, Graham);
insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name) values (3, Ali);
```

Now you can connect directly the record you want (I used an Edge called 'comesFrom' and subqueries to link the id fields but you could also directly use the @RID field)

```
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_id = 1) to (select from Country where c_id = 1);
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_id = 2) to (select from Country where c_id = 2);
create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_id = 3) to (select from Country where c_id = 3);
```

Finally you can query the fields you want without join operations:

```
select i_id, i_name, out('comesFrom').c_id as c_id, out('comesFrom').c_name as c_name 
from Immigrant unwind c_id, c_name

----+------+----+------+----+------
#   |@CLASS|i_id|i_name|c_id|c_name
----+------+----+------+----+------
0   |null  |1   |John  |1   |USA
1   |null  |2   |Graham|2   |UK
2   |null  |3   |Ali   |3   |PAK
----+------+----+------+----+------
```

In Orient Studio you should obtain a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: One more question. See below. create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_id = 1) to (select from Country where c_id = 1); This is linking one by one, record by record. So if there are a million records, do I have to do it at insertion time from the programming?

Comment: When I run this section, I get an error.

create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_id = 1) to (select from Country where c_id = 1)

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Class COMESFROM was not found

Comment: Hi tabarry, I've just tried you code and it works on my DB. Did you modify the sql/javascript code I posted ? How did you declare the class "comesFrom" (partial/all uppercase/lowercase) ?

Comment: Could you send the SCHEMA ?

Comment: Did you get the exception from creating the edge manually in BROWSE tab or with the javascript function ?

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using ? Can you provide us a DB-test for trying the code ?

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB does not support join.

You should declare the i_country field in class Immigrant as Link to Country class, or you can use Graph Model if you want bidirectional relationship.

If you want to use Direct link

you can insert immigrants like this

```
insert into Immigrant set id=1, name ='John', country = (select from country where id = 1 )
```

then

```
select id,name,country.id,country.name form Immigrant
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to display data from both tables as join syntax is not supported here and I want to join on country.c_id = immigrant.i_country.

Comment: And yes, how do I create the mentioned link? Or the graph model.

Comment: You don't use join as are not supported.

You will have direct link from immigrant record to country record

select *,country.* from immigrant

Comment: create class Immigrant . then create property immigrant.country link country

Answer (score 0):

you could speed up the insertion and link operations with a javascript function like this:

[image]

so the edge is automatically created when you decide to create a new person. You can also decide where to place the person:

[image]

Could it be helpful for you ?

Comment: Thanks! More than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have created a Document DB because I reproduced the issue by creating a Document DB and not a Graph DB and I get, like you, the same exception. This is because if you want to work with Vertices and Edges you must use the Graph DB type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again LucaS. Almost there but now the following error. com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #96: Invalid keyword 'UNWIND' Command: select i_id, i_name, out('comesFrom').c_id as c_id, out('comesFrom').c_name as c_name from Immigrant unwind c_id, c_name --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: Apology for asking so many questions. My next question is that I have done this. insert into Immigrant(i_id, i_name) values (3, Ali) and then create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 3) to (select from Country where c_id = 3). Now I add another immigrant so how do I create edge for this new record with an existing country because if I do this create edge comesFrom from (select from Immigrant where i_country = 3) to (select from Country where c_id = 3), the records get repeated.